# Need help with a SQL query that combines adjacent rows into a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need a solution to a problem that has the table structure as listed below.
Input

1 1/1/2009 Product1 
2 2/2/2009 Product2 
3 3/3/2009 Product3 
4 4/4/2009 Product4 
5 5/5/2009 Product5

Output

1 1/1/2009 2/2009   Product1 
2 3/3/2009 4/4/2009 Product3 
3 5/5/2009                   Product5

I tried using CTE. But was not very sucessful in extracting the second row value.
Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: How many columns will be in the returned set? Also, in row 3 the second date column is missing--would that be a null value, an empty string, or what?

Comment: returned set contains 4 columns . and yes, in row 3 , the second date column will be null, because there is no matching row for it to combine the date value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know whether Russ' answer helps you at all.  [Here is a link](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=KB;EN-US;q186133) to an article that explains how to add row numbers to the results of a query.  (Search for "row_number" to find the most likely example.)

Once you have a query numbering the rows properly, you should be able to throw that into a CTE, then select from it twice -- once for odd numbers, then again for even numbers.  Have each result return the even numbered value for joining (odd - 1 = even).  At that point, you can join the results of the queries and get two products on one row.

Comment: I have a query that uses CTE along with the row number generated as the first column. I cannot group any of the columns in the input table. The query returned only even numbered rows when I used the % 2 operator.

Comment: We'll probably need to see the query to see what's wrong.  I would guess that it's rough to place this into the comments.  For the comparison, you'll need (x%2 = 0) as well as (x%2 = 1).

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, John. This is the query I have been working on 
;With ProdListCTE As
 (
 Select
  Row_Number() Over(order by ProdTime asc) as row_id,
  ProdTime,       
  Desc,
  From ProdListStaged
 )
 Insert into ProdList (ProdTime1, ProdTime2, Desc)
  Select
   A.ProdTime,  
   B.ProdTime, 
   A.Desc,
  From
   ProdListCTE A Join    
   ProdListCTE B On A.row_id = B.row_id - 1

Comment: I used two CTEs, one for the odd rows and one for the even rows and select using a left outer join. 
Thanks, John.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for PIVOT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx
Here is a best shot with the info you gave, I do something similar in one of my apps.  You may need to use a dynamic SQL query if the pivot values change.

```
SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT [Date]
        ,[Product] 
      FROM [Values]
   PIVOT (Max([Date])
          FOR [Product]
           IN ('put date ranges here')) pvt
```

here is what mine looks like, this will allow for a set of different values. This is used in a form builder to retrive the values of user input

```
--//Get a comma delimited list of field names from the field table for this form
DECLARE @FieldNames varchar(max)
SELECT @FieldNames = COALESCE(@FieldNames + ', ', '') + '[' + CAST([FieldName] AS varchar(max)) + ']'
  FROM [Fields]
 WHERE [FormID] = @FormID

--//create a dynamic sql pivot table that will bring our 
--//fields and values together to look like a real sql table
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)
SET @SQL = 
 'SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT [Values].[RowID]
            ,[Fields].[FieldName]
            ,[Values].[Value] 
            FROM [Values]
      INNER JOIN [Fields] ON [Fields].[FieldID] = [Values].[FieldID]
           WHERE [Fields].[FormID] = ''' + @FormID + ''') p
   PIVOT (Max([Value])
      FOR [FieldName]
      IN (' + @FieldNames + ')) pvt'

--//execute our sql to return the data
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Russ. I will try using the PIVOT operator.

Comment: I had to finally go with CTEs, since I already had a query which was only giving me half the results.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually create a dummy column initially and create a cte.

Then, use cte and join them on the dummy key and the row number or a series which simulates sequential numbers.

Then, filter in the dataset to display only odd numbered rows

```
create table dbo.test
(
    id integer,
    currdate varchar(20), -- just to keep simple, not to mess with dates, took this as string
    productCode varchar(20)
);


insert into test values (1, '1/1/2009', 'product1');
insert into test values (2, '2/2/2009', 'product2');
insert into test values (3, '3/3/2009', 'product3');
insert into test values (4, '4/4/2009', 'product4');
insert into test values (5, '5/5/2009', 'product5');


with ctes as
(
    select
        't' as joinKey,
        id, -- serves as rownum or else create another using row_num() over partition by and order by
        currdate,
        productCode     
    from test
)
select
    c1.id,
    c1.currdate,
    c1.productCode,
    c2.id,
    c2.currdate,
    c2.productCode
from
(
    select
        joinKey,
        id,
        currdate,
        productCode
    from
        ctes
)c1,
(
    select
        joinKey,
        id,
        currdate,
        productCode
    from
        ctes
)c2
where c1.joinKey = c2.joinKey
and c1.id + 1 = c2.id
and c1.id % 2 = 1
```

The result is as shown below:

```
id  currdate    productCode id  currdate    productCode
1   1/1/2009    product1    2   2/2/2009    product2
3   3/3/2009    product3    4   4/4/2009    product4
```