# Help writing SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Need help with a SQL query that combines adjacent rows into a single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132560/need-help-with-a-sql-query-that-combines-adjacent-rows-into-a-single-row)

So this is how my table looks.

[image]

..and I need to write a query to get the output like this:

[image]

This is not a homework question.

Comment: Homework or not, still a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476186) or [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476186) and [lots more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=concat%2Brows%2BCSV+%5Bsql-server%5D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following answer is only valid for SQL Server 2005+:

```
  SELECT t.category,
         STUFF((SELECT ','+ x.prod
                  FROM TABLE x
                 WHERE x.category = t.category
              GROUP BY x.prod
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS prod,
         SUM(t.price) AS amt
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.category
```

Answer (score 0):

Some sample data to test with:

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(15), Price INT)

INSERT  @Sample
SELECT  1, 'Ford', 100 UNION ALL
SELECT  1, 'Cereal', 200 UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'Fruits', 30 UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'Fruits2',70 UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'Soap', 40

SELECT * FROM @Sample
```

And the query would be:

```
SELECT s3.ID, Stf.Conc, 
SUM(s3.Price) PriceSum
FROM @Sample s3 INNER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT s1.ID, 
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + s2.Name 
           FROM @Sample AS s2 
           WHERE s2.ID = s1.ID 
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') Conc 
       FROM @Sample s1) AS Stf
ON s3.ID = Stf.ID
GROUP BY s3.ID, Stf.Conc
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is asked many times...
The answer is always the same. Something like

```
SELECT Category, GROUP_CONCAT(PROD SEPARATOR ", ") AS Prod, SUM(Price) AS Amt FROM yourtable GROUP BY Category
```

should be ok.